# change theme in manifest not working

Tags: android, android-theme

i define two theme in styles.xml
AppTheme1 and AppTheme2:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff00ff</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#0000ff</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

when i change theme in application tag inside AndroidManifest.xml
my app theme doesn't any change and the app only use colors.xml and not styles.xml.
for example my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.maneshtsoft.blackdictionary">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/favicondark"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme2">
    <!-- OR AppTheme1 does not matter -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

just say that i use toolbar and AppCompactActivity  maybe help to answer.
thanks.

Comment: don't use same parent for your second theme, instead use `Theme.NoActionBar`

Comment: if using different parent then app crash by  force close and error in logcat : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: what you want basically? If you want to just change the colors and apply that theme to application then remove the **AppTheme2** and open `colors.xml` from res->values->colors.xml and just change the colors which will be affected into your AppTheme.

Comment: tell me, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: no i want to change app theme programmatically(runtime)

Comment: application theme will not change at runtime but you can change activity theme by using `setTheme()` must be called before `setContentView()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be the cache of InstantRun.
Did you try "Clean & Rerun"? If you use AndroidStudio 2.1 or higher, Select Menu -> Run -> Clean & Rerun.

Comment: i use android studio 2.1.2 and I did it ( Run -> Clean & Rerun.) but not help

Comment: That's odd. In my test application, the AppTheme2 in AndroidManifest.xml is worked. Did you try Re-install the application?
If you are trying to change app theme programmatically(runtime), Call setTheme(R.style.AppTheme2) before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState).